# Remove HTML element from DOM with VueJS

Tags: php, vue.js, codeigniter, vuejs3

I'm new with VueJS and i am writing my first project with it. For back-end i use PHP CodeIgniter 4 framework.
My VueJS runs almost as i wish but i have few issues from time to time...

Particular HTML is here:

```
<div v-for="(value, key) in loan_incomes.incomes" class="input-wrapper" :class="['wrapper-index-' + key]">
        
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="<?php echo lang('Income.income_date'); ?>"
            :name="'income[' + loan_incomes.incomes[key].id + '][income_date]'" 
            v-model="value.income_date" />
        
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="<?php echo lang('Income.amount'); ?>"
            :name="'income[' + loan_incomes.incomes[key].id + '][amount]'" 
            v-model="value.amount" />
        
        <select :name="'income[' + loan_incomes.incomes[key].id + '][income_type]'" v-model="value.income_type">
            
            <option value="">-- <?php echo lang('Loans.select_claim_type'); ?> --</option>
            
        <?php foreach($claim_types as $key => $value) { ?>
                
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo lang('Loans.' . $value); ?></option>
            
        <?php } ?>
            
        </select>
        
        <a @click="removeIncomeRow(key);" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
            <?php echo lang('Income.remove'); ?>
        </a>
        
    </div>
    
    <a @click="addNewIncomeRow();" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo lang('Income.add_new'); ?></a>
```

VueJS function addIncomeRow() works just fine, no issues with that.
But when i add new row and then try do delete it with removeIncomeRow function, then i get the error message...
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

VueJS methods are here:

```
methods: {
        
        letMeKnow: function() 
        {    
            console.log('I LET YOU KNOW');
        },
        
        removeIncomeRow: function(index) 
        {    
            if (this.loan_incomes.incomes[index].id !== undefined) {
                
                income_row_id = this.loan_incomes.incomes[index].id;
            
            } else {
                
                income_row_id = 0;
                $('.input-wrapper.wrapper-index-' + index).remove();
            }
            
            delete this.loan_incomes.incomes[index];
            
            if(income_row_id) {
                
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/admin/loans/removeIncomeRow",
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                    // contentType: "application/json",
                    data: {
                        'csrf_test_name': csrfHash,
                        'income_row_id': income_row_id,
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                .done(function( results ) {
                    
                    if (results.status !== undefined) {
                        
                        csrfHash = results.new_form_hash;
                        
                        $('input[name="csrf_test_name"]').val(results.new_form_hash);
                    }
                    
                    if(results.status) {
                        
                        $('.input-wrapper.wrapper-index-' + index).remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        
        addNewIncomeRow: function() 
        {    
            this.loan_incomes.incomes.push({'id': 0, 'income_type': '', 'amount': '', 'income_date': ''});
        }
```

And when i click on the link in browser's console, to see more about the error, then it says this:

```
_withDirectives(_createElementVNode("input", {
                type: "text",
                placeholder: "Laekumise kuupäev",
                name: 'income[' + loan_incomes.incomes[key].id + '][income_date]',
                "onUpdate:modelValue": $event => ((value.income_date) = $event)
              }
```

Is there easy way to fix that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's clear what happens exactly. `this.loan_incomes.incomes[index].id !== undefined` is wrong if there's no value, possibly should be `if (this.loan_incomes.incomes[index]?.id)`